# How can I know a software's install position in my CentOS?

Tags: centos, python

In my CentOS7 there are multi python, I check the default python version by:

```
# python3 -V
Python 3.6.0a1
```

but how can I know its position in my CentOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which python3` will show you the path to Python executable; if you want to find out the root dir where the Python library files are installed, use [`sys.prefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.prefix):

```
$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rpm -ql`. Like so:

```
$ rpm -ql python
/usr/bin/pydoc
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/share/doc/python-2.7.5
/usr/share/doc/python-2.7.5/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/python-2.7.5/README
/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/python2.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/python2.7.1.gz
```

`-q` = Query
`-l` = List

See `man rpm` for all options.

Or simply:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

...to see where the binary is.